# How can i set For-in loop max iterations?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `for(entry in array)`, where in `array` I have number of entr between 0 and an undefined number. How can I limit the for-in loop to a maximum of 10 iterations?

Comment: break the loop at ten?

Comment: yes this is what I would like, but I don't know how

Comment: if you iterate through an array, you need to use `for of` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert mentioned in a comment to my original answer, the variable `entry` is actually the index, not the value in the array, so you can use it to conditionally break out of the loop.

```
var array = [42,1,2,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,12]

for (entry in array)
{
    //check for exit condition
    if (entry == 10)
        break;

    //do stuff
    console.log(array[entry]); 
}
```

Output:

```
42
1
2
6
4
5
6 
7
8
9
```

Comment: If you're using `for … in`, `entry` is already a counter (/index). Your output is that counter, not the array value at that index.

Comment: @robertklep Good call. Answer edited.